# Java add program to startup

Tags: java, jna

I have used [jna](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) library to write to windows registry to add my program to startup. When I saw in the registry, it got added fine. I used the code

```
Advapi32Util.registrySetStringValue(WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", FILE_NAME, FILENAME_FILEPATH);
```

The save data in registry is like

```
key - program.jar
value - PATH/program.jar
```

If I double click the `program.jar` file, it gets executed fine, but why it is not executing at startup ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply put the jar file into startup folder?

Comment: I can, but the receiver demanded for not to have dependency on system. Try to code for startup also.

Comment: Make sure you have set the correct file separator for WIndows "\"

Comment: I have set them correctly. I have manually checked it in regedit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you double click on a Jar-File in Windows, Windows starts Java and pass that Jar-File as an argument to it, just like you double click .docx Files - Windows starts Word and pass that File as an argument to it.

With that registry command you have to do the same - start Java and pass the jar-File as an argument to it. Try using this command in your registry (you can try it on the command line first):

```
java -jar path/to/jarfile.jar
```

Maybe you'll see a console with `java`, if thats the case, you can use `javaw` instead.

Comment: Yeah, `javaw` is better.

Answer (score 3):

Try writing a `.bat` file to execute your program (`java -jar`) and set the `.bat` file path in registry.

Comment: I mentioned in the above comments that _but the receiver demanded for not to have dependency on system_

Comment: It is not a dependency of the system. You can distribute the .bat file with your program.